# How to restart Hangfire?

Tags: c#, hangfire

In my web project, after a user clicks on the *Restart* button I delete all tables and create them again, something like restart happens. But hangfire goes crazy and it seems it is looking for its enqueued jobs!

how can I stop and start hangfire completely?

Comment: You can run queries for this. Visit this link to refer more: https://discuss.hangfire.io/t/database-cleanup-sql-server/1318. Hope to help, my friend.

Comment: Thanks, @Tomato32 .My problem is I remove all tables, I want hangfire to create its tables too. or if it's not possible I should use your mentioned solution.

Comment: I think it'll be better if you redirect the user to log in page after clicking restart. So it will initialize Hangfire again. It's my solution :))